# Angular2 retrieve all elements with class name

Tags: angular, renderer

Can anyone help with how to find 'All' Elements with a particular class name in Angular 2?  I thought it would be trivial but it's giving me more problems that was prepared for.

```
<span class="classImLookingFor">foo</span>
<span class="classImLookingFor">Voo</span>
<span class="classImLookingFor">Moo</span>
```

I thought by doing what I have below would return all the elements with class "classImLookingFor" but it only returns the first instance.

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer){}
ngAfterViewInit(){
 const el = this.renderer.selectRootElement('.classImLookingFor');
 this.renderer.setElementAttribute(el, 'tabindex', 0);
}
```

Afterwards, my markup looks like this.

```
<span class="classImLookingFor" tabindex="0">foo</span>
<span class="classImLookingFor">Voo</span>
<span class="classImLookingFor">Moo</span>
```

It seems like I should be able to create a Renderer array, but that doesn't seem to work either. I need to manipulate each element with that class name.

Comment: you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.classImLookingFor')`

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  That works perfectly.  For some reason though, document.getElementsByClassName didn't work for me,.  Thanks for the speedy response.  I was making it overly complicated

Comment: can you upvote my answer as it helped you

Answer (score 93):

> Doesn't this return all the elements in the DOM? Is there a way how to return only elements generated by the Angular component I'm "in"?

You need to...

1. Inject `ElementRef` in the `constructor`

   ```
   constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private elem: ElementRef){}
   ```
2. Find the elements you are searching using `querySelectorAll` api.

   ```
   ngAfterViewInit(){
       // you'll get your through 'elements' below code
       let elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.classImLookingFor');
   }
   ```

[The answer @Aravind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43377323) has provided is not the best for the performance as it will search the whole DOM.

This solution will just search the DOM inside the current component.

Comment: this is the actual way to get the rendered (querySelectorAll) value in Angular

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Using `document` worked as expected but this approach does not. Unfortunate because I can see the benefit of doing it this way.

Comment: @JeneralJames, I think it is not working for you because you are searching element outside the elementRef and this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll is searching only inside of it.

Comment: `ElementRef<HTMLElement>` for type-safety.

Answer (score 17):

Angular 10+ document compatibility with SSR, import:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'
```

then inject:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: HTMLDocument) {
    }
```

And use in your component/ directive like this:

```
doSomething(): void {
 this._document.querySelectorAll('.classImLookingFor')
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Answering as the comment worked for the OP.

You should be using

```
document.querySelectorAll('.classImLookingFor')
```

Comment: Doesn't this return all the elements in the DOM? Is there a way how to return only elements generated by the Angular component I'm "in"?

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek, u're right, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376081/angular2-retrieve-all-elements-with-class-name/#48928778)

Comment: I upvoted because this is useful if you want to reference an element in the document which is outside the Angular component you are "in".

Answer (score 5):

This might be a little over-simplistic for your use case, but is there any reason you can't use the native DOM functions, like so?

```
var domRepresentation = document.getElementsByClassName('classImLookingFor');
var angularElement = angular.element(domRepresentation);
```

Comment: modified version of the comment

Comment: Looked right past the comment the first time I read this, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm very new to Stack Overflow and saw there were 0 answers. Is it best practice to comment first instead of answering the question outright @Aravind ?

Comment: Where does `angular` come from? Is that AngularJS or Angular2+?

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do but the latest provided by Angular 9+ versions are:

1.import Inject and DOCUMENT in angular.

```
import {Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
```

2.Then create a reference in the constructor of the required class.

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: HTMLDocument) {}
```

3.Use as a variable with all javascript methods available.

```
selectElement(): void {
 this._document.querySelector('#mySelectedId');
}
```

Comment: what is the benefits of using this `DOCUMENT` of angular/common and  native document.* ?

Answer (score 0):

Use case;
Press escape key -> Remove border of marked row

[image]

```
  resetMarkedRows():void{
    const rowContainer = document.getElementById('row-container');
    //get row node list
    const rowNodes = rowContainer && rowContainer.querySelectorAll('.row-outer');
    //convert node list to an array
    const rows = Array.from(rowNodes) as HTMLElement[];
    const markedRows = rows.filter((row:HTMLElement)=>{
      if(row.style.border == "1px solid rgb(0, 136, 255)"){
        return row
      }
    });
    markedRows[0].style.border = "none";
  }
```

Answer (score -4):

you need to use DOM in angular

```
var element=document.getElementsByClassName("X").item(0);
```

it works for me!

Comment: might work in AngularJS, would not work in Angular 2+

Comment: You should not access DOM directly like that, it breaks Angular's abstraction over platform. Use ViewChild and/or Renderer2.