# How to use javascript code in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to rotate element(clockwise on downscroll & anti-clockwise on upscroll) while scrolling the page. For that i use javascript code.But it's not working in angular.I just use the CDN links in index.html.Javascript code is not working in angular.[Want to rotate starburst in top right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCLMG.png)

Html File:

```
<div class="starburst discount" id="star">
   <span>17%</span>
 </div>
```

My Javascript File is:

```
<script> 
var star = document.getElementById("star");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
star.style.transform = "rotate("+window.pageYOffset+"deg)";
</script>
```

Is there any other way to achieve the element rotate in Angular?Can anyone help with this?Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I don't need rotating on hover.i want to achieve this when scrolling.Got it?

Comment: @Arthi which version of angular you are working on?

Comment: https://codepen.io/runamuk0/pen/OPNXyV. 
Just Modify click event to scroll in this sample

Comment: Angular 6.0.9@Javascript_Lover

Comment: Its fine.where to include the js code in angular.I just gave the code inside the index.html file.but it does not work @NullPointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of how to handle window scroll event in angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3z533s. I have used `HostListener` to bind event handler to window scoll event. Refer: [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)

Comment: It's working.. But the problem is am displaying multiple products as in the above figure. The first element is alone rotate while scrolling rest of the list doesn't rotate.

Comment: How can i achieve this for all starbursts in all products?

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376081/angular2-retrieve-all-elements-with-class-name

Comment: U r just amazing..I had been searching for this since morning..Thanks its working..

Comment: Happy to help:-)

Comment: I want the content inside starburst remains constant while the starbursts are rotating.I had created h5 tag inside span and gave the content inside it and make its position fixed..But still the content also rotating how can i fix this?

Comment: can u help me with the issue?

Comment: How are you showing that star background? Using `background-image` or using `img`?

Comment: No its in css file

Comment: .starburst {
  background: #00c851;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  z-index:999;
}
.starburst,
.starburst span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.starburst span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.starburst:before,
.starburst:after ,
.starburst span:before,
.starburst span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

Comment: .starburst:after {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.starburst span:after {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.starburst span:before {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.discount {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
}
#star {
  left: 95%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

Comment: Is `<span>17%</span>` the only element inside the `div`?

Comment: <div class="starburst discount" id="star" #rotateEl>
            <span><div class="Percent"> 17%</div> </span>
          </div>      .Percent{
    font-weight: 500;
    position: fixed;
}

Comment: Add `element.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.transform = "rotate(" + -window.pageYOffset + "deg)";` after `element.style.transform = "rotate(" + window.pageYOffset + "deg)";`. Revert `<span><div class="Percent"> 17%</div> </span>` to the old one.

Comment: Actually am hardcoded the discount price now and i will dynamically bind with the value getting from server in future. Will this work for that too?

Comment: It will. Unless you change the html structure. Updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpd5hs

Comment: Its work..But why the starburst shape becomes irregular while rotating?

Comment: I think some parts of the starburst itself also remains stable while scrolling that's why its shape become irregular while scrolling..Did you notice this?

Comment: I did. Seems to be an issue with how you created that star background. Try to fix it yourself. I have spoiled you enough already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularjs Directive for DOM Manipulation 
[Angular Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Am using Angular 6 version

Comment: sorry i thought you were talking about angularjs