# Attach event to all elements with a specific class

Tags: css, angular, events, angular5, angular6

I would like to attach an event listner in my component that will fire for all elements that have a specific class.

These are generated by a third party component so i cannot attach it at the point where they are created.

i would like to do effectively do the equivalent of the following jquery statement but in angular where .day is the class.

```
$(document).on('mousedown','.day',function(jsEvent){ 

});
```

Thanks

Comment: I think that in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376081/angular2-retrieve-all-elements-with-class-name can help you to get the elements, and using renderer2 you can listen the events https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen, but not sure

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) to attach the listener:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '.day'
})
export class DayDirective {

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    yourFunction(event: Event): void { ... }

}
```

To wire up the Directive, you add it to the module that requires it. This could be your app module, a shared module or a feature module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DayDirective,
  ],
  ...
})
export class YourModule {}
```

Comment: How would i attach this. Normally the directive is placed onto an element?

Comment: You need to add the directive to the module that requires it. I've added an example.