# Traversing DOM to remove class using typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need an help with navigating to a  element in a table. The html looks like below,

```
<table role="grid">
    <thead class="ui-table-thead">...</thead>
    <tbody class="ui-table-tbody" ng-reflect-columns="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-template="[object Object]">...</tbody>
    <tr tabindex="0" class="ui-selectable-row ng-star-inserted ui-state-highlight" ng-reflect-data="[object Object]">...</tr>
</table>
```

This is my code to navigate:

```
if(this.table){
    console.log(this.table.tableViewChild.nativeElement);
    let element = this.table.tableViewChild.nativeElement.children;
    for(let key in element){
        if ((element[key].classList).contains('ui-table-tbody')) {
            (element[key].classList).remove('ui-state-highlight');
          }
    }
}
```

The above code doesnt help.I dont see any change. Can someone please let me know how to remove the foll. class dynamically 'class="ui-state-highlight"'.Thanks in advance.
any leads please?

Comment: `.contains(...)` returns a boolean, not an element.

Comment: The thing is that you're checking an element that contains `ui-table-tbody` class but not `ui-state-highlight` so based on the information and code snippets you gave there's nothing wrong with having nothing happening. Or should your `tbody` element contain `ui-state-highlight` class at some point ?

Comment: @Romuald yes thats right. tbody doesnt have 'ui-state-highlight'. Its the tr element which holds the 'ui-state-highlight' class. So how do i traverse to tbody then tr and find the class?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply check if `(element[key].classList).contains('ui-state-highlight')` ?

Comment: @ Romuald I tried and got this error.  ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'contains' of undefined or null reference

Comment: How do you declare `this.table`?  Are you getting the whole table/`tableViewChild` by Angular's `ViewChild`?

Comment: @ Aleks Grunwald yes that right

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@ViewChild` to declare a table:

An element declared by `@ViewChild` is only available after the view is initialized and this happens in `ngAfterViewInit`.

So try to put your function in `ngAfterViewInit` Angular Lifecycle Hook.

More about this topic:
[Angular 2 @ViewChild returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256703/angular-2-viewchild-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Also, I would would just use searching by a class name, but since you are using Angular, it would be proper to search only in the component, not the whole DOM.

Check this question/answers:

[Angular2 retrieve all elements with class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376081/angular2-retrieve-all-elements-with-class-name)

So, I would try to follow @Paritosh answer and do sth like this:

1. Inject ElementRef in the constructor:

   `constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private elem: ElementRef){}`

and then

2. Use ngAfterViewInit:

   ngAfterViewInit() {

       let elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.ui-table-tbody');

       for (let elem of elements) {

           elem.classList.remove('ui-state-highlight')
       

       }

   }